# How to set cursor on same input after every ajax submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with textbox message and submit button as below

```
<form action="#" id="messageform">
     <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

And I have ajax to submit form as below.

```
$("#messageform").submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My problem is I have to manually place cursor at ***message textarea*** after clicking submit button.
Is there any way to set cursor default on ***message box***. Even after I click on submit button cursor ***should remain on message textarea***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use <kbd>**[.focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)**</kbd> after click as below:

```
$("#messageform").submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#message").focus();//this here
});
```

Comment: That worked for me. I am able to vote after 11 minutes. Anyways. Can you please tell me importance of using e.preventDefault(). And passing e as perimeter?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default action to be triggered. Fo example instead of your text box imagine that you were clicked on a link, `e.preventDefault()` will prevent from redirecting to a new page. The `e` in `e.preventDefault()` actually stands for `event`

Comment: In specific to your scenario here, `e` is an `event` related to `form` and here it is `submit` event of `form` which is been `prevented`